# How to convert SSL certificates PEM <--> PKCS#12/PFX and PEM <--> PKCS#7/P7B using cryptography module

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to do some SSL certificate conversions using python, specifically between:
    PEM <--> PFX
    PEM <--> P7B

I already have a solution for PEM <--> DER.
Namely:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.x509 import (
    load_der_x509_certificate,
    load_pem_x509_certificate,
)

form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    cert = form.cleaned_data.get('file')
    der_file = pem_to_der(cert)

form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    cert = form.cleaned_data.get('file')
    pem_file = der_to_pem(cert)


def pem_to_der(cert):
    try:
        cert_to_der = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert.read(), 
            default_backend())
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return cert_to_der.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.DER)


def der_to_pem(cert):
    try:
        cert_to_der = load_der_x509_certificate(cert.read(), 
            default_backend())
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return cert_to_der.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM)
```

I do have a solution using subprocess.call, as in:

```
def pem_to_pfx(private_key_path, cert_path, name, passwd):
    return subprocess.call("openssl pkcs12 -export -out " + "tmp/" 
        + name + ".pfx" + " -password pass:" + passwd + " -inkey " 
        + private_key_path + " -in " + cert_path, shell=True)
```

but I would prefer to avoid this.
Anybody know of a way to do these conversions using the python module cryptography?

Answer (score 0):

`cryptography` does not currently support serialization to PKCS12/PFX or PKCS7 (although it can [parse PKCS12](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.pkcs12.load_key_and_certificates)). The project determines development priorities via user reports with concrete use cases so please file an issue!

As a stopgap you can produce [PKCS12 using pyOpenSSL](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.PKCS12) (which uses `cryptography`'s bindings), but we'd prefer to build a good API that you can directly use without an additional dependency.